# Selenium web driver / java / hover + click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am looking to click a menu link, but the link only appears if the cursor hovers above it stretching the drop down.  Therefore, the automation is unable to click it like it would normally with my click function.  I did some research and used `moveToElement`, and `clickAndHold`.  The latter has given me some hope, but it is far from perfect.  I am finding it not clicking at all half the time, and sometimes it does click but clicks a different menu link in the drop down.  Any ideas how I can make it work 100% of the time?

```
public  String hoverClick(String object, String data){
    APP_LOGS.debug("Moving the mouse");
    try{
        WebElement tab;
        WebElement link;
        tab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'FOO')]"));                                  
        link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'BAR')]"));

        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.clickAndHold(tab).click(link).perform();
        return Constants.KEYWORD_PASS;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL+"Unable to move the mouse/click"+e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the HMTL of the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try with following:

```
act.moveToElement(tab).moveToElement(link).click(link).perform();
```

Here, we hover over the element which populates dropdown(and which contains element to be clicked on) and then move to element to be clicked on and then click it.

Comment: thank you for the response.  I was hopeful, but it did not work.   I tried these two:      act.moveToElement(tab).moveToElement(link).click(link).perform();
   act.moveToElement(tab).clickAndHold(tab).moveToElement(link).click(link).perform();

Comment: Please try again with `act.moveToElement(tab).moveToElement(link).click(link).build().perform();` In this, I added `build()` method.